# OpenAPI Swagger API not sending "Authorization" header along the API call

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, spring-restcontroller, springdoc-openapi-ui

**Environment :**

- Java 17
- Service is on Spring Boot 3
- OpenAPI dependencies :         'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0',
  'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.1.0',
  'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0',

I am trying to send a value through the header, but looking at the chrome dev console, the API call does not have the headers in the request. (FYI : The API was working fine with the headers before upgrading from springfox to openapi)

---

---

**When sending other headers types, I can see in the Chrome dev console. For example :**

API Definition :

```java
@GetMapping(value = "somevalue")
@Operation(summary = "Get something")
@Parameters({
    @Parameter(
        name = "authorization1",
        description = "Access Token",
        required = true,
        in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
        schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class),
        example = "12345"),
    @Parameter(
        name = "code",
        description = "Code",
        required = true,
        in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
        schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {"A", "B", "C", "D"})
    )
})
public List<IIRDto> getII(
    @Parameter(required = true) @NotNull @RequestParam List<Long> idsOfSomething
) {
    // CODE
}
```

[image: Working when the header is not named "authorization"]

---

**But when the header name is "authorization" it doesnt show up in the request headers.**

API Definition :

```java
@GetMapping(value = "somevalue")
@Operation(summary = "Get something")
@Parameters({
    @Parameter(
        name = "authorization",
        description = "Access Token",
        required = true,
        in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
        schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class),
        example = "12345"),
    @Parameter(
        name = "code",
        description = "Code",
        required = true,
        in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
        schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {"A", "B", "C", "D"})
    )
})
public List<IIRDto> getII(
    @Parameter(required = true) @NotNull @RequestParam List<Long> idsOfSomething
) {
    // CODE
}
```

[image]

Please let me know your suggestions to pass authorization headers from UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Authorization` header can be added globally to all APIs through the `OpenApi` bean, as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {
  @Bean
  public OpenAPI openAPI() {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearer-key";
    return new OpenAPI()
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
        .components(
            new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                    new SecurityScheme()
                        .name(securitySchemeName)
                        .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                        .scheme("bearer")
                        .bearerFormat("JWT")
                )
        );
  }
}
```

After that, a small lock icon will appear on the right side of the APIs and if clicked the authorization popup will show up, where the value of the `Authorization` header can be inserted.

[image: authorize_popup]

There will also be the authorize button in the top right corner of the `swagger-ui` page which does the same.

[image: authorize_button]

---

To selectively define protected APIs rather than globally, delete the line `.addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))` from the configuration, and add the following line above each protected API:

```java
@Operation(security = { @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer-key") })
```

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for your answer. May I know is this the only way to do it (instead of having it for selective API) ?

Comment: This is the only way I've found so far and I don't think there is another way that would be simpler than this one.

Comment: I copied and pasted your `@Configuration` code, but it didn't work. The button is there, but the "Available authorizations" is blank (as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieVE6.png) screenshot). I have a dynamic Swagger UI config in my `application.yml` (`springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    path: /swagger-ui
    config-url: /swagger-ui/config`). Could it be the reason?

Comment: I copied and pasted your `@Configuration` code, but it didn't work. The button is absent. I have a dynamic Swagger UI config in my `application.yml` (`springdoc:   swagger-ui:     enabled: true     path: /swagger-ui     config-url: /swagger-ui/config`). Could it be the reason?

Comment: I tried to move the OpenApi bean from my gateway to my microservice, but it didn't help. This time, the button is there, but the "Available authorizations" is blank (as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieVE6.png)). See [this Code Review page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287625/is-this-how-you-do-a-dynamic-spring-cloud-gateway) for more details on what my overall architecture is

Comment: * please ignore the first reply: I can neither edit nor delete it