# Enabling an Authorize button in Swagger UI declaratively

Tags: java, swagger-ui

How do I enable the "Authorize" button in Swagger UI? I got it all set up, but if the endpoints require authentication, it's not going to work straight from the UI. I need to be able to pass JWT tokens as `Authorization` header values

Do I need to pass some yml property?

Should I write something here?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = info(version = "1.0", title = "Hello World API"), security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "/* here */"))
public class HelloworldMreApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(HelloworldMreApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

I also tried this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@Tag(name = "Message Controller")
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "basicAuth")
public class MessageController {

@GetMapping("/hello-world")
// ...
```

I got the button, but it's not useful. Once I click on it, I get a popup that only says "Available authorizations"

[image]

A more verbose variation produced the same result

```java
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "basicAuth",
description = "authorization with JWT token", scheme = "token",
bearerFormat = "bearer")
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035621/23106712) doesn't seem to be helpful in my case. I'm sure there's a declarative solution to this (which I would prefer). One guy in the comments asked whether it could be achieved with annotations too, and the person who posted the answer shared [this link](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html). I don't see any annotation-based solutions there, though

## UPD

What I found is that it doesn't have to do with JSONs served to Swagger UI at all. What matters is this annotation at a service controller class:

```java
@RestController
@Tag(name = "Message Controller")
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "basicAuth", scheme = "bearer")
public class MessageController {
```

That service's Swagger UI now has this button:

[image]

However, my Gateway's UI still gets a disfunctional button (see the first screenshot above)

You may compare the service's and the Gateway's Swagger UI JSONs: they are for all intents and purposes identical. I checked whether the differences they *do* have may have influenced the outcome (like `http` vs. `HTTP`). They don't

Still confused as to what to do. I tried putting `@SecurityScheme(..)` on the Gateway's main class (the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) or on a random controller class. It didn't help

```json
// service

{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Hello World API",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8090",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/joy": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Message Controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "getMessageOfJoy",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/auth/hello-world": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Message Controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "getHelloWorld",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "principal",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/error": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error_3",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error_2",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error_5",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error_6",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "head": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error_1",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "patch": {
        "tags": [
          "my-error-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "error_4",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "SuccessMessage": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "FailureMessage": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "GET",
              "HEAD",
              "POST",
              "PUT",
              "PATCH",
              "DELETE",
              "OPTIONS",
              "TRACE"
            ]
          },
          "request_path": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "basicAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
// gateway

{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Hello World API",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Api-Gateway-V2"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/joy": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Message Controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "getMessageOfJoy",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/v1/hello-world": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Message Controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "getHelloWorld",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "principal",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "style": "FORM",
            "explode": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "exampleSetFlag": false,
              "types": [
                "string"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "SuccessMessage": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ]
          }
        },
        "exampleSetFlag": false,
        "types": [
          "object"
        ]
      },
      "FailureMessage": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ]
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ],
            "enum": [
              "GET",
              "HEAD",
              "POST",
              "PUT",
              "PATCH",
              "DELETE",
              "OPTIONS",
              "TRACE"
            ]
          },
          "request_path": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ]
          }
        },
        "exampleSetFlag": false,
        "types": [
          "object"
        ]
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "basicAuth": {
        "type": "HTTP",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    },
    "extensions": {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77448233/10231374) out, you can globally enable authorization for all endpoints through OpenApi bean.

Comment: @Toni thank you, but can I do it declaratively?

Comment: @Toni I cracked it, see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I pinned it down! It took me a while. Here's an MRE:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui-mre</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>swagger-ui-mre</name>
    <description>swagger-ui-mre</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```yaml
server:
  port: 8100
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui
```

```java
package com.example.swaggeruimre;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(version = "1.0", title = "Hello API"))
public class SwaggerUiMreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SwaggerUiMreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.swaggeruimre;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Tag(name = "Hello Controller")
@RestController

// ↓ here, it enables the button declaratively

@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "bearer-key",
        description = "authorization with JWT token", scheme = "bearer",
        bearerFormat = "JWT")
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public HelloMessage getHello() {
        return new HelloMessage();
    }

    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class HelloMessage {
        private final String message = "Hello!";
    }
}
```

[image: 2024-02-11_14-11-14]

The `Authorize` button works!

Let's copy the OpenAPI JSON. **It's a good JSON, one that produces a button**

[image: 2024-02-11_14-26-53]

Now, let's imagine that we receive that JSON from elsewhere (like a Gateway receiving it from a microservice). For simplicity, the source and the recipient are going to be the same in this example

```yaml
server:
  port: 8100
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui
    url: /open-api
```

```java
package com.example.swaggeruimre;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class OpenApiController {
    @GetMapping("/open-api")
    public String getOpenApi() {
        return """             
                {
                  "openapi": "3.0.1",
                  "info": {
                    "title": "Hello API",
                    "version": "1.0"
                  },
                  "servers": [
                    {
                      "url": "http://localhost:8100",
                      "description": "Generated server url"
                    }
                  ],
                  "paths": {
                    "/hello": {
                      "get": {
                        "tags": [
                          "Hello Controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "getHello",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HelloMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "components": {
                    "schemas": {
                      "HelloMessage": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "securitySchemes": {
                      "bearer-key": {
                        "type": "http",
                        "description": "authorization with JWT token",
                        "scheme": "bearer",
                        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                """;
    }
}
```

[image: 2024-02-11_14-37-46]

Still works!

Now, let's change the JSON we return and make it a **bad JSON**. I already know the trick. Replace `"type": "http"` with `"type": "HTTP"`. The result:

[image: 2024-02-11_14-42-52]

Now the button doesn't work!

You may be wondering, "Why would you want to turn a good JSON into a bad JSON?" To simulate what `OpenApiV3Parser` does!

Suppose I return not a string, but an object (which I got by, for example, calling `openApiV3Parser.readContents(/* json */).getOpenAPI()`):

```xml
<!-- you need to add this -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
package com.example.swaggeruimre;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class OpenApiController {

    @GetMapping("/open-api")
    public OpenAPI getOpenApi() {
        return new OpenAPIV3Parser().readContents("""             
                {
                  "openapi": "3.0.1",
                  "info": {
                    "title": "Hello API",
                    "version": "1.0"
                  },
                  "servers": [
                    {
                      "url": "http://localhost:8100",
                      "description": "Generated server url"
                    }
                  ],
                  "paths": {
                    "/hello": {
                      "get": {
                        "tags": [
                          "Hello Controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "getHello",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HelloMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "components": {
                    "schemas": {
                      "HelloMessage": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "securitySchemes": {
                      "bearer-key": {
                        "type": "http",
                        "description": "authorization with JWT token",
                        "scheme": "bearer",
                        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                """).getOpenAPI();
    }
}
```

Let's see
[image: 2024-02-11_14-56-33]
[image: 2024-02-11_15-01-26]
[image: 2024-02-11_14-57-59]

Maybe we just need to tell our `ObjectMapper` to ignore nulls?

```java
package com.example.swaggeruimre;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

[image: 2024-02-11_15-06-21]
[image: 2024-02-11_15-06-47]
[image: 2024-02-11_15-07-41]

Nope! It's precisely because once we return objects instead of strings, those nested enum properties, e.g. `SecurityScheme.Type`, are serialized into upper-case strings which Swagger UI can't handle!

Considering they override `toString()` for each of their enums to return lower-case values

```java
// like so

public class SecurityScheme {
    /**
     * Gets or Sets type
     */
    public enum Type {
        APIKEY("apiKey"),
        HTTP("http"),
        OAUTH2("oauth2"),
        OPENIDCONNECT("openIdConnect"),
        MUTUALTLS("mutualTLS");

        private String value;

        Type(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }
```

I imagine they had a problem with this before

Then, it's not solved completely!

To recap:

1. If Swagger UI receives an OpenAPI object (not a string), it deserializes it in a way that results in upper-case enum values. Those `toString()`s are not called during serialization!
2. When an underlying OpenAPI has upper-case enum values, specifically `SecurityScheme.Type`, the `Authorize` button doesn't work!

I see these approaches for the Swagger UI team:

1. Make Swagger UI stomach upper-case (good)
2. Tell Jackson to serialize Open API enums to lower-case strings (a kludge)

```java
// here's one way to do it

public class SecurityScheme {
    /**
     * Gets or Sets type
     */
    public enum Type {
        APIKEY("apiKey"),
        HTTP("http"),
        OAUTH2("oauth2"),
        OPENIDCONNECT("openIdConnect"),
        MUTUALTLS("mutualTLS");

        private String value;

        Type(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        @JsonValue
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }
```